# Using the -r command line Ruby switch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The -rname Ruby switch can be only used to require something that already exists in Ruby's library, or can I use it to also require from the command line an external file created by me? For example, I'm trying to run a program "loaddemo.rb" with a "loadee.rb" file already required:

```
ruby -rloadee loaddemo.rb
```

It doesn't work. What is my mistake here?

Answer (score 2):

You can use it to require other files too but require is a thing, import another one. To require something, it has to be in your load path too.

Try `-I .` to insert the current directory in your load path if `loadee.rb` is there

```
ruby -r loadee -I . loaddemo.rb
```